# Change text color in knitr for Word

Tags: ms-word, knitr, r-markdown

I have an R Markdown file that outputs a data table into Word (unfortunately, my company's security settings won't allow it to interface with LaTeX) and I would like to color code the text in the table based on a classification factor to make it more readable. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1:5), runif(5, 100, 200), c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 2)))
colnames(df) <- c("N", "Value", "Category"
kable(df, format = "markdown", row.names = FALSE, align = 'l')
```

I would like whatever has a Category value of B, for example to be red in the output. I haven't found a command in knitr for Word that allows colors to change (I think this problem would be doable with LaTeX) which may stop me right there. Any thoughts or ideas how to get this to work?